# create base repository using generics

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I have a c# asp.net4 mvc app. 
I am using entity framework to connect to sql server. 
I am using Auto Mapper to map domain models to view models.
I want to create a base repository with generics to perform create/read/update/delete operations instead of writing the method 50 times for each different class. This is what I have so far but it does not work.

```
    public class BaseRepository<T, U> where T : class
    {
        public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            using (ApplicationEntities context = new ApplicationEntities())
            {
                IEnumerable<T> models = context.Set<T>();
                return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<U>>(models);                
            }
        }
    }
```

Errors:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<U>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Edit: as per Tim S, updated method. Now only the Auto Mapper error is left.

Comment: What is db? It seems no member in db named `T`

Comment: `db.T` - You can't do that. Try `CreateObjectSet<T>` or something.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel sorry typo. db.T changed to context.T

Comment: You can't do that either.  T is a type, not a member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`DbContext.Set<TEntity>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method. And you'll need to add a generics restriction on `T`, because `Set<TEntity>()` has one:

```
public class BaseRepository<T, U> where T : class
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<U> GetAll()
    {
        using (ApplicationEntities context = new ApplicationEntities())
        {
            IEnumerable<T> models = context.Set<T>();
            return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<U>>(models);                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question updated with your answer. Now only Auto Mapper error remains.

Comment: @That-_-Guy__ updated my answer: the return type of the method was wrong.